# fibonacci with huffman Encoding

Tags: fibonacci

If the frequencies of n symbols are represented by the first n Fibonacci number
(1,1,2,3,5,…), then what is the average number of bits required to represent the n
symbols by Huffman coding algorithms?

I am not able to figure out how should i proceed with it

Comment: I would start generating these trees for small n, and then see if a pattern emerges. Have you done this?

Comment: NB: this has nothing to do with the `dsa` tag. So you are addressing the wrong crowd.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9boi.jpg)

[image]

Unsure about the average bit formula(got it online), but I think this is pretty much the approach.

<<<<56>>>>